# Multiple remote queues to a single local queue

Tags: ibm-mq

Is it possible to have this scenario using Websphere MQ? We want to have multiple MQ servers each of which has the same queue manager, remote queue, transmission queue and chanel defined on it (i.e.the MQ servers are effectively clones). Each server is on its own domain.

Each of these remote queues will point to a local queue on another (centralised) MQ box which is used to aggregate the messages coming in from the various remote queues.

[image]
Is this possible? If not, what would you suggest as an alternative option?

Kind regards.

Comment: Are you sending persistent or non-persistent messages?

Comment: Ideally persistent - I'm guessing by the question that's an additional complication?

Comment: A standard RCVR channel can accept connections from multiple SDR channels, but persistent messages increment channel sequence number.  I have never tried but assume this would fail for all but one channel due to seqnum issues.  MQ clustering can do what you want, but you would not implement it exactly as you have mentioned.  In most cases each queue manager should be a unique name.  applications connecting to the queue manager via client connections do not need to know the name and can specify null or a `*` to connect to any queue manager.

Comment: Also having multiple RCVR channels will accomplish what you want. Is there a driving reason to have just one RCVR channel on the destination queue manager?  For example CHANLAN1, CHANLAN2, etc, even if you did call the remote queue manager the same name this would not have the seqnum issue.  Depending on the number of queue managers this could be simpler solution than clustering.  If the centralized queue manager needs to send back response messages clustering would have some advantages.

Comment: Firstly thank you JoshMc for the advice, I appreciate it.  The reason for having a single RCVR channel is purely ignorance about what is and isn't possible. Preferably we would want message persistence to prevent message loss so in which we would need the multiple RCVR channels.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good design.  Your queue managers and channel names should have unique names.

- Edge queue managers: MQE1, MQE2 & MQE3
- Central queue manager: MQC1

There are 2 typical channel naming standards:

- {fromQMgr}.TO.{toQMgr}
- {fromQMgr}.{toQMgr}

i.e. MQE1.TO.MQC1 or MQE1.MQC1

I like to go with the shorter version since a channel name has a maximum length of 20.